# Need help with an Arduino project using a RTC and LEDs

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, rtc

I need some help with a project I am doing involving the DS1307 RTC. I am trying to make what is essentially a way to mins quickly check the time which involves nine LEDs slowly lighting up every 10 so that I can quickly check time but looking at it. :[image: Here is a rough 3D model of the housing of the arduino] So far I've tried TimeAlarms but I can't figure out how to do this. I have a Arduino Uno by the way.

Can someone possibly help?

Comment: start by learning how to light up the LEDs .... then learn how to use the  DS1307 RTC .... tutorials can be found on the web

Comment: please explain what `slowly lighting up` actually means

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQW pin on the DS3231 or DS1307 to create 1sec pulse, read it on your Arduino. There are very good libraries are available (like RTClib from adafruit).